# Why does randalthor only have 1 rep?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is he some sort of super mod that can't gain rep any more or something?

Comment: See http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4497/4421

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: @randal'thor, lol, did you finally just search for questions with your name and find this after nearly a year?

Comment: @user1717828 No, I saw this when you first posted it, but couldn't comment then. The question body is really funny, btw :-D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Suspended users have their reputation locked at 1.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91627/why-do-suspended-users-have-a-reputation-of-one)

You can tell when a user is suspended, as there is a banner displayed above their profile indicating how long they will be suspended, and providing a short reason why.